# IIS ASP.net Web service, creating an excel instance

Tags: asp.net, excel, iis

I'm creating an Excel document (which is then sent to the user) in an ASP.Net Web Application.

Everything works correctly when testing within visual studio, however when I run the application in IIS I get the following error:

```
The machine-default permission settings do not grant Local Activation permission for the COM Server application with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} and APPID Unavailable to the user IIS APPPOOL\*** SID (***) from address LocalHost (Using LRPC) running in the application container Unavailable SID (Unavailable). This security permission can be modified using the Component Services administrative tool.
```

I've read through [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/jayendra/how-to-create-excel-file-in-Asp-Net-C-Sharp/) and [this](https://stantsui.blogspot.co.uk/2014/08/the-machine-default-permission-settings.html) and tried to set up the permissions through the Component Services but I still have yet to resolve the issue.

The line which I believe is causing the issue is
`Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();`

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Do not use Office Interop in ASP.NET](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office). Use a library that doesn't depend on it, such as EPPlus, NPOI, Closed XML, Aspose, or Office XML SDK.

Comment: Thanks mason, switching to EPPlus has resolved the issue

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by switching to [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) instead of Interop